# Просканировать папки cache

Tags: android, кэширование

Подскажите, как просканировать? Во всех приложениях на телефоне "/data/data/" папку /cache/

Также интересно как просканировать во всех приложениях только на флешке, если она есть "/Android/data/cache/"?

Answer (score 3):

Без рута никак.

Все дело в том, что каталог кэша приложения является частным каталогом к которому можно получить доступ только из самого приложения.

Каталог находится в пути возвращаемой методом `Context.getCacheDir()`